# how to match a node from A to B with py2neo

Tags: python, neo4j, cypher, py2neo

I have this cypher

> MATCH(qs:Persons)<-[r0:CONNECTED_TO]-(qi0:Documents)-[r1:LOCATED_IN]->(qe:Locations)
>   return qs

And I want to create the same result in DSL py2neo.

Until now I have this

```
graph = py2neo.Graph("bolt://localhost:7687", auth=("neo4j", "neo4j"))
matcher = py2neo.NodeMatcher(graph)

qs = matcher.match("Persons",name = "Jhon").first()
qi = matcher.match("Documents")
print list(     graph.relationships.match( (qs, qi), "CONNECTED_TO"   )  )
```

but that code raise this follow exception.

```
ValueError("Node %r does not belong to this graph" % n)
```

How I can create the same cypher with py2neo?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that you create the `matcher` object with the same `graph` used in your `graph.relationships.match` call.

Comment: Yes I was looking that but still I receive the error.  I fact I just want to do this. MATCH(qs:Persons)<-[r0:CONNECTED_TO]-(qi0:Documents)